# Implement the JWT middleware in golang using gin package and secure the other APIs?

Tags: go, jwt

I want to secure my APIs that an authorized user can access my APIs. Here the router is given below:-

Router.go

```
//here the customer will register.
Route{"SaveUser", "POST", "/signup", controller.SaveUser},
//here the customer will login with its username and password.
Route{"LoginUser", "POST", "/login", controller.Login},

//APIs that a valid user can access
Route{"SaveCustomers", "POST", "/customer", controller.SaveCustomers},
Route{"GetCustomers", "GET", "/customer", controller.GetCustomers},
Route{"GetCustomer", "GET", "/customer/:id", controller.GetCustomer},
Route{"UpdateCustomers", "PUT", "/customer/:id", controller.UpdateCustomers},
```

Controller.Login.go

```
package controller
import(
  // "encoding/json"
  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
  "go-training/Template1/config"
  "go-training/Template1/models"
  "fmt"
  "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
  "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
  "strings"
 )

 type User struct {
   Email string `json:"email"`
   Password  string    `json:"password"`
   jwt.StandardClaims
 }

 type user struct {
   email     string 
   password string 
 }
 func Login(c *gin.Context) {
  email := c.PostForm("email")
password := c.PostForm("password")
reqBody := new(user)
err := c.Bind(reqBody)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
response := ResponseControllerList{}
conditions := bson.M{"email_id":email,"password":password}
data, err := models.GetAllUser(conditions)
dataCount, err := models.GetRecordsCount(config.SignupCollection, conditions)
counter:= 0
for _, signup := range data {
    if email == signup.EmailId && password == signup.Password {
        //fmt.Println("heloo")
        counter = 1
    }
}
if counter == 1 {
    fmt.Println("Match!")
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.GetSigningMethod("HS256"), &User{
        Email: email,
        Password:  password,
    })
    fmt.Println(token)
    tokenstring, err := token.SignedString([]byte(""))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(tokenstring)
 }

}
```

The above code will generate the token for user then how would I make a middleware that compare each given token in postman header with the database save token and

> **If** the authorized user will come then it will access the above mentioned APIs. **If** it is not a authorized user then it will not access the above APIs and gives the error of `unauthorized user`.

I don't understand what should I have to write for this. I googled it so many times and find the stuff like [this](https://github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt) but I don't understand the code in easy way. Can any one tell me what shall I do to secure the APIs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We can also grouping the routes and make the routes private as given in [this](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#grouping-routes) link.

Answer (score 4):

Use [gin-jwt](https://github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt) package to secure your APIs using JWT.

> It uses jwt-go to provide a jwt authentication middleware. It provides additional handler functions to provide the login api that will generate the token and an additional refresh handler that can be used to refresh tokens.

Example from [gin-jwt](https://github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt) README.md:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func helloHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    claims := jwt.ExtractClaims(c)
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "userID": claims["id"],
        "text":   "Hello World.",
    })
}

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(gin.Logger())
    r.Use(gin.Recovery())

    if port == "" {
        port = "8000"
    }

    // the jwt middleware
    authMiddleware := &jwt.GinJWTMiddleware{
        Realm:      "test zone",
        Key:        []byte("secret key"),
        Timeout:    time.Hour,
        MaxRefresh: time.Hour,
        Authenticator: func(userId string, password string, c *gin.Context) (string, bool) {
            if (userId == "admin" && password == "admin") || (userId == "test" && password == "test") {
                return userId, true
            }

            return userId, false
        },
        Authorizator: func(userId string, c *gin.Context) bool {
            if userId == "admin" {
                return true
            }

            return false
        },
        Unauthorized: func(c *gin.Context, code int, message string) {
            c.JSON(code, gin.H{
                "code":    code,
                "message": message,
            })
        },
        // TokenLookup is a string in the form of "<source>:<name>" that is used
        // to extract token from the request.
        // Optional. Default value "header:Authorization".
        // Possible values:
        // - "header:<name>"
        // - "query:<name>"
        // - "cookie:<name>"
        TokenLookup: "header:Authorization",
        // TokenLookup: "query:token",
        // TokenLookup: "cookie:token",

        // TokenHeadName is a string in the header. Default value is "Bearer"
        TokenHeadName: "Bearer",

        // TimeFunc provides the current time. You can override it to use another time value. This is useful for testing or if your server uses a different time zone than your tokens.
        TimeFunc: time.Now,
    }

    r.POST("/login", authMiddleware.LoginHandler)

    auth := r.Group("/auth")
    auth.Use(authMiddleware.MiddlewareFunc())
    {
        auth.GET("/hello", helloHandler)
        auth.GET("/refresh_token", authMiddleware.RefreshHandler)
    }

    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, r)
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate it i see this example but i don't understand how i use it with the my code.